# Centering list items horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a pricing table template where I've removed one of the list elements reducing it from 3 to 2 elements. I'm attempting to centre the remaining 2 list elements with parent elements `<ul>` and `<div>` but cannot get it working.

I've tried the following without success so I'm looking for some guidance

```
div {
    display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and also

```
.cd-pricing-list {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}
.cd-pricing-list > li {
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

My current example is here https://jsfiddle.net/5d0gec7u/1/

The source code is from this site https://codyhouse.co/demo/pricing-tables/index.html

Comment: You are missing the semi colon in these lines `text-align:center`  should be `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
.cd-pricing-list{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

see here [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5d0gec7u/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Flex is good, but here's a more compatible solution:

1. Add `text-align: center` to the containing `<ul>`.
2. Remove `float: left` from the list items.
3. Add `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` to those list items.

Normally you'd also add `text-align: left` to "reset" the alignment from the list itself, but since the contents are also centered there's no need to here.